# Flutter Firebase How to convert DocumentSnapshot to Model Json inside a model class

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-freezed

I have this Firebase Document that I want to convert to a JSON and add Id to it when using it within the app.

```dart
factory Recipe.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = doc.data()!;
    return Recipe.fromJson(data).copyWith(id: doc.id);
  }
```

I get the following error
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
factory Recipe.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Recipe.fromJson(data).copyWith(id: doc.id);
  }
```

According to the [FlutterFire usage documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

```
DocumentSnapshot doc;
doc.data() is of type Map<String, dynamic>;
```